# How can I show images in DataGridView column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, datagridviewcolumn

I am creating an app to store offers on a server. The app stores the products and displays them in rows of a C# DataGridView. The datagridview looks like this:

[image: offer app]

I download the product image from a web server URL in byte [] format. then I do a bitmap conversion and finally I give the image a fixed size of 300 x 300.
The problem with all this is that the image column does not adapt to the size of the image where I would like it to remain with a size that could not be less than that of the image. also the other columns are too wide for how small the content is.

This is my new code:

```
private void cargadatos()
    {

        try
        {

            conectar();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT codigo," +
                " nombre, Id_Familia, precio" +
                " from OFERTAS  ORDER BY Id_Familia, codigo asc;", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn() { HeaderText = "Gesture" };
            da.Fill(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("foto", Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
            
            
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("http://encuadernadores4.synology.me/somisata/fotos_articulos/"+drow["codigo"].ToString()+".jpg");
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

                    
                    Bitmap bitmap=new Bitmap(img);
                    Image resizedImage = resizeImage(bitmap, new Size(200, 200));

                    drow["foto"] = imageToByteArray(resizedImage);/*File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\alexg" +
                             "\\Desktop\\fotos_articulos\\" + drow["codigo"]
                             .ToString() + ".jpg");*/
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                
            }

            //dtgvOfertas.RowTemplate.Height = 200; //determinamos el alto de las filas
            dtgvOfertas.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True; 
            //dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode =  DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; 
            dtgvOfertas.Columns["foto"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;//null error
            dtgvOfertas.DataSource = dt;
            int numColumnas = dtgvOfertas.ColumnCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumnas; i++)
            {
                dtgvOfertas.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment =
                    DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                dtgvOfertas.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment =
                    DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            }      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        desconectar();

    }
```

[error null produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4eel.png)

Comment: Is there some reason the code creates a `DataGridViewImageColumn` … `DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn() { HeaderText = "Gesture" }` … ? … but it is never used or inserted into the grid… ? …

Comment: I am not sure if I am following your question. You state that… _”the other columns are too wide for how small the content is.”_ … this is because you have the line of code… `dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;` … this will resize each column to the SAME width to fit the width of the grid. If you want the other columns to be a smaller width, then you may have to manually set each columns width and then set the last image column to “Fill.” This is just a guess as I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "DataGridViewImageColumn … DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn() { HeaderText = "Gesture" }"                                                                                                                     this part of the code is an error, I should delete it.
How could i give a fixed size to the other columns? or at least give the image column a fixed size and that the other columns adapt to the space they have left.

Comment: It can be confusing as the grids `AutoSizeColumn` properties come in two flavors. One is specific to the “GRID” as your code does…`dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode = …` … this applies to ALL the columns in the grid. On the other hand you can do the same thing to the “individual” columns in the grid like… `dtgvOfertas.Columns["ColName"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;` this will auto size ONLY that column to fit the grid.

Comment: Is what is important to know… is that IF the “GRID’s” `AutoSizeColumnMode` is set… THEN… this will OVERRIDE any individually set column auto size mode. So, In your case you need to remove the code that sets the “grids” auto size column mode and then set each column individually. Example, you can fix the width of the first three columns then fill the next two or fix the first four and fill the last.

Comment: I have changed that part of code for this: //dtgvOfertas.RowTemplate.Height = 200; //determinamos el alto de las filas
                dtgvOfertas.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
                //dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode =  DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
                dtgvOfertas.Columns["foto"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                dtgvOfertas.DataSource = dt;
                int numColumnas = dtgvOfertas.ColumnCount;         but it gives me an error because it receives a null

Comment: As I previously articulated… the two lines of code will NOT work “together” … `dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;` … AND … `dtgvOfertas.Columns["foto"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;` … The first line of code is OVERRIDING the second line of code. That is why you should remove the first line of code. Please [edit] your question and “ADD” your updated code and what line of code throws the error… do not add it as a comment. Some may not read the comment.

Comment: i have changed the code but i have an error

Comment: You are getting that error because the column is not yet in the “GRID.” It is in the table `dt` but the code has not yet assigned `dt` to the grids `DataSource`, so there is no `Columns[“foto”]` … move … `dtgvOfertas.Columns["foto"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;` … AFTER … `dtgvOfertas.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: Thank you so much for everything. the program adapts the content perfectly. Thank you.